# how to delete particular cookie from cookies using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cookies, session-cookies

This is code which shows URL and delete image for delete cookie. add and display function is working but how to delete ??

```
function backLinks(){
    var pathname = window.location;
    var patientName = document.getElementById("general:patientDetailName").value;
    var cookieTimeVal = jQuery.cookie('PCC_Back_Button');
    if( cookieTimeVal== null){
        cookieTimeVal ="";
    }
    // for writing Cookie
    var stringCookie = "<span class='backLinkText1'><img src='../images/deleteImg.png' alt='' class='backLinkDeleteButton' onClick='deleteBackLink()'/></span><a class='backLinkText' href=\""+pathname+"\"> Patient History For \""+patientName+"\"</a>"+cookieTimeVal;
    jQuery.cookie('PCC_Back_Button', stringCookie , { expires: 1 });

    // read Cookie and set in HTML
    jQuery('#backButtonSpan').append(
        jQuery('<div>').attr({style:'padding-top:-10px;' }).append(cookieTimeVal)
    );
}
```

**

```
function deleteBackLink(val){
        jQuery.cookie(val, null);
    }
```

**

How can I create a delete function and what parameter will I pass to it?

Comment: Does what you have not work?  I suggest the chicken parm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got a correct answer ...

in this i will replace cookie and delete inner html

```
 function backLinks(stringValueAndName, patientName, patientDOB){
                var pathname = window.location;
                var cookieTimeVal = jQuery.cookie('PCC_Back_Button');
                if( cookieTimeVal== null){
                    cookieTimeVal ="";
                }

                var time = new Date();
                var spanId = time.getTime();

                // for wright in Cookie
                var stringCookie = "<span id ="+spanId+"> <img src='../images/deleteImg.png' class='backLinkDeleteButton' onClick='deleteBackLink("+spanId+")'/><a class='backLinkText' href=\""+pathname+"\">"+stringValueAndName +patientName+' ('+patientDOB +')'+"\</a></span>"+cookieTimeVal;
                jQuery.cookie('PCC_Back_Button', stringCookie , { expires: 1 });
                // read Cookie and set in HTML
                jQuery('#backButtonSpan').append(
                        jQuery('<div>').attr({style:'padding-top:-10px;' }).append(cookieTimeVal)
                    );
            }
    function deleteBackLink(val){
        jQuery('#'+val).remove();
        var stringCookie = jQuery('#backButtonSpan div').html();
        jQuery.cookie('PCC_Back_Button', stringCookie , { expires: 1 });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a cookie with jQuery, set the value to null:

```
jQuery.cookie("name", null);
```

So your function will work - just pass the cookie name as a parameter:

```
deleteBackLink("name");
```

Comment: this is output Patient History For "krishan",  Patient History For "krishan",  Home Page     and i wants to delete only home page what should i pass parameter ??

Comment: can you see what cookie is being set? If the cookie name is 'krishan', just use jQuery.cookie("krishan", null); or deleteBackLink("krishan");

Comment: please check question carefully

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. A cookie is a cookie.

`The closest it comes is the HTTP Only flag, which allows a cookie to be hidden from JavaScript(mean client side)`. (This provides a little defence against XSS cookie theft).

A cookie is a cookie. `(Again, client side code can't touch an HTTP only cookie)`